# Quick javascript help about switch case

Tags: javascript

Hey basically i was wondering if it was possible to put the attribute of an object as a condition in the switch case. Something like this.

```
function Person (age,name){
this.age = age
this.name = name
 }

var person1 = new Person(22,"Ken")
var person2 = new Person(42,"Ben")
var person3 = new Person(62,"Len")


switch(the attribute here lets say it was age for example){


case person1: Do something;    Basically age for person1 do this age for person 2 do this etc.
break;
case person2: Do something;
break;
case person3: Do something;
break;
}
```

Sorry if this is unclear i'm really new in javascript and i was wondering of something of this sort was possible.

Comment: If it has an rvalue you can test it.  But not the way your code looks.  You can test person1.age  You can't test the parent, that isn't an rvalue.  To spin through your objects you need to put them into an array, loop and test their age.

Comment: Yea thanks I had to use a loop didn't think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
switch(this.age){
  case x:
}
```

`this` represents a parent object. So if I say this.age it represents the age of the parent object, without needing to specify an age.

Comment: Ok it really works with this? What does this mean exactly in that specific case?

Comment: I assumed he knew about `this` due to the usage in the original code - but I will edit it to make an explanation.

Comment: If you want to use `this`, then the code block should be in a method of the instance. According to asker's code structure, this is not quite applicapable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
function Person (age,name){
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}

 var person1 = new Person(22,"Ken");
 var person2 = new Person(42,"Ben");
 var person3 = new Person(62,"Len");
 switch(person.age){
     case 22:
        alert("the person is " + person.name);
        break;
     case 42:
        //do something here;
        break;
     default:
        //do something default;
        break;
 }
```

And you sure can put an attribute of an object into the switch/case condition as it is just like some other variable, so why not.

Comment: Thank you for the reply not what i was looking for but i didn't even know you could do that! Always great to learn something

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do:

```
function Person(age, name) {
  this.age = age;
  this.name = name;
}

var person1 = new Person(22, "Ken");
var person2 = new Person(42, "Ben");
var person3 = new Person(62, "Len");

var person, people = [person1, person2, person3];
while (p = people.shift()) {
  console.log("Q: Do you think " + p.name + " is old?");
  console.log("A: " + isOld(p));
}

function isOld(person) {
  switch(true) {
    case person.age < 40:
      return "Not at all.";
    case person.age < 60:
      return "I prefer not to comment.";
    default:
      return "Who? The grandpa?";
  }
}
```